# Vibration remains while braking even after machining rotors

Tags: ford, brakes

Had a vibration in brakes took it back three times for this vibration. They eventually turned my rotors. It's still doing it, just not as bad and only when going down mountains. Van has only 20k miles as it is only 10 months old. It's not as bad, but it's still there. Are they being honest or should I have someone else look at it???

Comment: You may check if the disc surface shows some blue hotspots (4 to 8 spots of approx 20mm diameter). Turning the rotors could be then a solution, provided you change and bed the disc pads once done.

Answer (score 3):

It could be bad pads / uneven pad wear.

You say it's only when going down mountains - are you riding the brakes regularly down the grade?  Don't do that! Downshift the car into a lower gear and allow the motor to help slow the car, only apply the brakes in brief spurts if you are moving too quickly. Lightly riding the brakes all the way down will cause the rotors to heat and the pads to overheat, potentially boiling the brake fluid as well.

When pads overheat, they can then leave bits of pad deposit on "hotspots" on the rotors, and then when you use the brakes again later, they will pulse, which is what makes a rotor feel "warped" (and why simply machining down the surface fixes it -- the excess pad deposits are cut off by the lathe).

On a relatively new car, you shouldn't need new pads at 20k... but if you've put 20k miles on it in 10 months, you're obviously driving it *a lot*.  It's not completely inconceivable to need pads at 20k, but it's rare... unless you're towing or something.

Answer (score 1):

Could be any number of things honestly...  I honestly doubt it is the brake pads.  But as @ZPrime notes, riding the breaks can generate crazy heat and that could screw up the wheel bearings pretty quickly.  At any rate, I think the most likely causes are wheel bearings, tie rod ends or other suspension components or bad wheel balance.  It could also be a frozen caliper (leading to unequal pad pressure) but I think that isn't likely on a newer car.  Also not likely but possible is rotors were turned improperly (i.e. the machined surface is no longer parallel to the plane of rotation of the rotor) or the rotor was not installed true to the hub.

Answer (score 1):

When ever you turn rotors, you should replace and re-embed new pads too.  If you didn't do that, you still perhaps have a mis-matched groove.

A heavy vehicle going down mountains will eat brakes like crazy.